# 4 first order coupled linear pde and 1 extra equation for 5 unknown functions by method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Is the system below solvable by the method of characteristics or any other analytical method for $h_n(x,t)$, $u_n(x,t)$ for $n=1,\,2$ and $p(x,t)$?

If so, how can be solved?

$$h_{nt} + h_{nx} + \frac{1}{2} \;u_{nx} = 0    \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (*)$$

$$u_{nt} + u_{nx} + p_x = 0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (**)$$
$$h_2(x,t) = 1-h_1(x,t)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(***)$$

Where $h_n(1,t)$, $\;u_n(1,t)$ for $n=1,\,2\;$ and $\;p(1,t)$ are given for all times.

Also initial conditions are

$$  h_n(x,0) = 0 , \quad u_n(x,0) = 0, \quad p(x,0) = 0 . $$

I have found 
$$u_1 - u_2 = W(x-t)$$

using method of characteristics by cancelling $\;p\;$ term in (**). Then using (*)

$$h_1 = G(x-t)-\frac{t}{4} W'(x-t)$$
Then I have used boundary conditions and initial conditions to determine what $W\;$ and $\;G$ are. I use

$$\xi = x-t $$

Then for $\xi>1$,  I have $W(\xi)=0, \; G(\xi)=0$.

For $\xi<1$,

$$W(\xi)= E(t)$$

Here, $E$ is known. To determine what $G$ is, I have used $W'(x-t) = W_\xi = -E_t$.   Therefore,

$$G(\xi) = F(t)$$

Question 1: Am I in the right direction?

Question 2: The solutions are found for $x=1$. 
How can I find the solutions for all $x>1$ and $t>0$?

Thanks !

Comment: What is $p(x,t)$? Is it known?

Comment: Thanks @Dmoreno. p(x,t) is not known as well as others!

Comment: Then, how can you determine it without an extra equation?

Comment: Hi @Dmoreno. I just improved my question. Actually I had 5 equations in total for 5 unknowns. Thanks.